# KeePassX 0.4.3 no tray icon and not in unity launcher

Tags: 12.04, launcher, indicator

I use keepassx as passwort manager and just moved from 10.04 to 12.04 with unity.

I would like that keepassx uses its tray icon. Unfortunally this option is greyed out in my installation. Several reinstallations did not change anything.

[image]

whitelist is set to [all].

Another bug seems to be, that keepassx does not show up in the unity bar when it is running. This leads to the problem that there will be multiple instances runnig when I try to open it via the dash.

Any fix for that? I could not find any!

Comment: I have the same problem, here is the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/keepassx/+bug/992582

Answer (score 1):

I think they disabled this feature. But you can compile keepassx from the sourcecode, that fixed it for me.

Remove keepassx via software center , apt or what you like. Go to www.keepassx.org and download the sourcecode. Extract the files and change into the directory. Open a terminal. Type:

```
qmake-qt4
make
sudo make install
```

You need the qt4 libs for this. Make sure you have the following packages installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-core libqt4-dev libxtst-dev
```

Now you can use the tray icon again.

Comment: Did not worked for me, same behaviour as before

Comment: This did work for me, thanks. Ubuntu 12.04, unity.

Answer (score 0):

Enable [precise-proposed repositories](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed).

Then execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -t precise-proposed install bamfdaemon
sudo apt-get -t precise-proposed install unity
```

And restart.

Comment: Maybe make a note about how this is only intended to solve half of the OP's question. Or am I missing something?